# Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i tried in onCreate() method to make new thread and start it but the app freezes and the message still same (Cannot access database on the main thread  since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.)

also tried Runnable and Handler same message
i searched alot for the same issue i found runOnUIThread still same issue

any Articles or videos that would help please refer it 
any missing code you want to review refer it too
thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.popularmovies.DataBase.AppDatabase;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.DataBase.FavoriteMovies;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> arrayMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerViewAdapterFavorite adapterFavorite;
    private String dataRetrieved;
    private static final String TAG = "MAINACTIVITY";
    private String top_rated = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=*****";
    private String MoviesURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=*****";
    private AppDatabase mDb;
    private List<FavoriteMovies> allFavoriteMovies=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDb=AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        networkUtilites(false);
        getArrayMovies();
        RecyclerViewAdapter();




        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                allFavoriteMovies= mDb.taskDao().loadAllTasks();
            }
        });

        for(int i=0;i<allFavoriteMovies.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(allFavoriteMovies.get(i).getTitle());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sorting_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.most_popular:
                Toast.makeText(this, "MostPopularClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arrayMovies.clear();
                networkUtilites(false);
                getArrayMovies();
                RecyclerViewAdapter();

                return true;

            case R.id.top_rated:
                Toast.makeText(this, "TopRatedClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arrayMovies.clear();
                networkUtilites(true);
                getArrayMovies();
                RecyclerViewAdapter();

                return true;

            case R.id.favorite:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                RecyclerViewAdapterFavorite();




                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    public void networkUtilites(Boolean check) {

        NetworkUtilites ob = new NetworkUtilites();
        if (check) {
            ob.setMoviesURL(top_rated);
        } else {
            ob.setMoviesURL(MoviesURL);
        }

        try {
            dataRetrieved = ob.execute().get();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public void getArrayMovies() {

        try {


            if (!dataRetrieved.equals(null)) {
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(dataRetrieved);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("results");

                //System.out.println(parentArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject movieDetails = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String poster_path = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";
                    poster_path += movieDetails.getString("poster_path");
                    String original_title = movieDetails.getString("original_title");
                    String overview = movieDetails.getString("overview");
                    int vote_average = movieDetails.getInt("vote_average");
                    String release_date = movieDetails.getString("release_date");
                    int id =movieDetails.getInt("id");

                    ListItem ob = new ListItem(original_title, poster_path, overview, vote_average, release_date,id);
                    arrayMovies.add(ob);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }

    public void RecyclerViewAdapter() {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, arrayMovies);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

    }

    public void RecyclerViewAdapterFavorite()
    {
        if (allFavoriteMovies != null) {
            adapterFavorite = new RecyclerViewAdapterFavorite(this, allFavoriteMovies);
            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFavorite);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }

    }





}
```

TaskDao

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies.DataBase;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface TaskDao
{

    @Query("SELECT * From movies")
    List<FavoriteMovies> loadAllTasks();

    @Query("DELETE From movies")
    void deleteallTasks();

    @Insert
    void insertMovie(FavoriteMovies favoriteMovies);

    @Delete
    void deleteMovie(FavoriteMovies favoriteMovies);

}
```

FavoriteMovies

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies.DataBase;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Ignore;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "movies")
public class FavoriteMovies
{


    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private  String image;
    private  String title;
    private  String overview;

    @Ignore
    public FavoriteMovies(String image, String title, String overview) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public FavoriteMovies(int id, String image, String title, String overview) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }




}
```

AppDatabase

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies.DataBase;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {FavoriteMovies.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase  extends RoomDatabase
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="FavouriteMovies";
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static AppDatabase sInstance;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(sInstance==null)
        {
            synchronized (LOCK){
                sInstance= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class,AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return sInstance;

    }

    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.popularmovies, PID: 5342
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.popularmovies/com.example.android.popularmovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Comment: You can have your `@Dao` class's methods [return `LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable) or possibly [an RxJava type](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava). Or, set up a Java `Executor` (e.g., `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`) and have that `Executor` execute your database I/O. In [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.5/Bookmarker), I use the `LiveData` approach for queries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for freezing is because you are putting the task on runonuithread this means its running on the same thread as the UI and would block the system.

You can try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask. Which has an easy to use API for short multithreading purposes.

Another way is to create new java threads in onCreate that does no run on the ui thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){yourcodehere})
t.start()
```

Comment: Note that `AsyncTask` will be marked as deprecated in Android 11.